# QT MVC pattern not updating view - specific SimpleTreeModel example

Tags: c++, qt

I have had problems in my own code to get the views to update after  model data is updated.

I then took the SimpleTree example from QT and added a timer in TreeModel to change the data after 10s and then invoke the same set data function used in the constructor to update the model. The code is below for the slot that executes on the timer timeout. No matter what I try, the view does not update. The setDate and emit dataChanged were some attempts.

In my own code, I have a XML-RPC call updating the data, but considering I dont even get the simpleTreeModel to work, I suppose that would be a long shot.

Is there something fundamental that I am missing here?

```
void TreeModel::slotTimeout(void)
{
   QStringList tmp;
   tmp << "qaz";
   tmp << "wsx";
   tmp << "edc";
   setupModelData(tmp,rootItem);
   setData(QModelIndex(),QModelIndex());
   emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex());
   qDebug() << "Timer update";
}
```

Comment: The following link shows the example you say but in this case they are doing it editable. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html

Comment: I assume the model is based on a QAbstractItem model? Try using a QStandardItemModel in the first hand. Regarding the QAbstractItemModel you have to take care to really implement all necessary functions and to really call all necessary notification functions!

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
@eyllanesc: I did the same test with the timer on the editable example and it also does not update.

Comment: @tob: I will try using the QStandardItemModel. I *assumed* that the examples would implement all the required functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleTreeModel example is for static models only. It lacks the implementation of the required QAbstractItemModel functions to update the model.

Have a look on the [detailed description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#details) of the models documentation in order to see what should be implemented.

The problem is, that the required methods are implemented as empty methods by default so you will not get any error messages if something is missing. It will just not work.

In addition it‘s a bit tricky to do the necessary data changed emits.

Within the *setData* method you have to `emit dataChanged()`.

Within the also necessary *insertRows* you have to call the methods `beginInsertRows(...)` and `endInsertRows()` in order to get the required signals emitted.

A first approach toward the MV paradigma is to use the **QStandardItemModel**. It provides all the necessary implementation if a *QStandardItem* is sufficient what it usually will be.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer more completely. I appreciate it. I have seen these references to the emits and the beginInsertRows etc in my searches and it now makes more sense. I will read through QStandardItemModel and see if it would do the job. I suspect it will.